# Tandem position - front or back

Tags: long-distance, tandems

My ride buddy and I were "volunteered" to ride a tandem bike for a 40 mile, somewhat hilly, charity ride.

We're running into the issue of who should be in the front on the tandem. Both of us are capable cyclists who bike commute and do a lot of fast fitness cycling.

Main difference is that my buddy is a stronger climber.

So, what are the criteria for tandem riding? Who is the most effective "driving"? Maybe we should periodically swap? Should the "muscle" be in back or front?

Comment: What kind of bike are you going to be riding? Will it fit you both? What kind of road surface will you be riding over? Will you have a chance to go on practice rides?

Comment: All I know is that you don't generally want to make the blind guy the captain.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(My experience, for context: my girlfriend and I have ridden tandems quite a bit -- in the last 6 months we put in a few thousand touring miles on our tandem, and we've been riding tandems for several years now.)

There are several factors to consider when deciding who's going to be the stoker (at the back) and who's going to be the captain (at the front):

- The first and most important consideration is **who's comfortable with what**.  If one of you is a lot more trusting (or trustworthy), that's your primary consideration.
- Another thing you should take into account is **weight**.  The person driving the bike should ideally be the heavier person.  This is just a matter of physics -- the heavier you are, the more you can affect how much the bike turns.  In a pinch, it's better to have a heavier person who can more readily avoid obstacles.  The better your communication and teamwork, the less important this is.
- The last consideration is **Geometry**.  If the bike is built for a taller person in the front and a shorter person in the back (most tandems are), you should probably put the taller person in the front.  Assuming you're both at around the same fitness level, this should fit nicely with the previous rule, because taller people tend to weigh more. :-)

Tandems are a whole lot of fun, but you need to go into it with the right attitude.  With the wrong attitude, you'll hate it, and you'll likely make each other miserable.  Here are some tips:

- **Communicate** more than you think is reasonable.  Especially at first, you should both be talking a lot.  The more you talk, the better it'll be.
- Remember you're part of a **team** now.  If the cadence is good for you but bad for your buddy, it's bad for both of you.  You'll both need to adjust some and meet in the middle.
- Be **trusting**.  If you try to do the other person's job, you'll both be unhappy.  Communicate your needs and let your buddy do their job.  (This is especially important for the stoker.)
- Be **understanding**.  If you're driving and your stoker says they're getting nervous about how fast you're taking corners, *slow down*.  Yes, you're probably doing just fine, but riding with an unhappy stoker is going to make you slower in the end.  Conversely, if you're the stoker and the cadence is messed up, understand that the captain is probably doing their best to keep the cadence in tune -- it's not as easy as you might assume!
- **The stoker is in charge**. This sounds weird at first, but it's important.  The stoker tells the captain where to go and when to turn; the captain figures out how to get there.  If the stoker says "stop", you stop.  In a situation where two experienced cyclists are riding together, this balance of power is crucial for everyone to remain happy.  The stoker is going to feel powerless by nature of their fixed handlebars, so the captain needs to give something back.

Tandems are **fun**.  They go bloody fast, and you've got somebody to talk to all the time.  You've got incredible amounts of power, and you can cruise at 30 mph with reasonable effort.  Don't forget to stop and enjoy the moments of speedy bliss, and you'll have a great time.

A couple of additions:

- To answer the final portion of the original question, it doesn't matter who sits where in terms of strength.  You're both equally connected to the drivetrain, and can both give as much power as your legs will produce.
- Don't periodically swap.  Figure out who's going to be where, and practice before the ride.  If you're going to be pack riding, be very very careful, as tandems aren't as agile as single bikes.
- The stoker position feels bumps a lot more than you normally feel them on a road bike.  Part of this is their position directly over the rear wheel, and part of it is an inability to see the road.  Suspension seat posts are a good idea for the stoker position.  Most importantly, *warn* your stoker if you see bumps coming, and coast briefly so they can stand up.

Comment: Please define "stoker".

Comment: @wdypdx22: captain=front, stoker=back.  The stoker adds more fuel to the engine.

Comment: @ Benson and darkcanuck - So, the strong guy is on the back? And, I get to steer? Awesome!

Comment: It doesn't actually matter where the power sits. :-)

Answer (score 1):

General rule is: Whoever is bigger should ride in the front.

Comment: Why should the "bigger" rider ride in front?

Comment: It is easier to control the bike if you are bigger/stronger than your stoker.  Captain has responsibility to start and stop the bike, you want that person to be the stronger of the two.